# What is wrong with this simple javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can confirm that this.batch_well_range_columns().length will return an integer of 8.

```
    var column_html = "<select>";
    for (i = 0; i < this.batch_well_range_columns().length; i++) {
        column_html + "<option value=" +  this.batch_well_range_columns()[i] + ">" + this.batch_well_range_columns()[i] + "</option>";
    }
    column_html + "</select>";
    console.log(column_html)
    return column_html
```

The last console.log() is just returning the select tag. It ignores the loop completely.

Comment: Try using `+=` in your code like `column_html += "</select>";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do concatenation properly. Use `+=`

```
var column_html = "<select>";
for (i = 0; i < this.batch_well_range_columns().length; i++) {
    column_html += "<option value=" +  this.batch_well_range_columns()[i] + ">" + this.batch_well_range_columns()[i] + "</option>";
}
column_html += "</select>";
```

`a += b` is a short form for `a = a+b;` So in our case column_html + "somthing" will do a string concatenation, but there is no variable there to receive the returning value.

Comment: Don't ever quit drinking coffee. You make terrible simple mistakes. So embarrassed.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch

```
column_html + // ...
```

to

```
column_html = column_html + // ...
```

That way, you modify `column_html`.

Otherwise, you're creating new strings, but they're not being assigned to anything!

Answer (score 0):

```
 column_html + "<option value=" +  this.batch_well_range_columns()[i] + ">" + this.batch_well_range_columns()[i] + "</option>";
    }
 column_html + "</select>";
```

you need `+=` for string concatenation.

```
 column_html += "<option value=" +  this.batch_well_range_columns()[i] + ">" + this.batch_well_range_columns()[i] + "</option>";
    }
    column_html += "</select>";
```